Simulator not creating a MIDI output device?
I'm working with AudioKit and Apple Vision Pro headset. When building for the headset, creating a midiOutput device works as expected and I can send MIDI data (it shows up as Apple Vision Pro Bluetooth on macOS Audio MIDI Setup App / or any software VSTs).
But when building the App to Apple Vision Pro Simulator in Xcode 16.0 Beta 3, a MIDI output Device is not created.
Has anyone had success with the Vision Pro Simulator and creating MIDI output devices? (I've just been using the standard MIDI.openOutput() call,
Summary:
Trying to create a MIDI output device for visionOS that can be used in the visionOS Simulator.
AudioKit's MIDI.openOutput() works as expected when building for device, but no output is visible in macOS Audio MIDI Setup when building the App to the Xcode Simulator.
Expectation:
I would expect a MIDI output device to be visible when using the simulator too.
